# How to remove removed apps OS X URL schemes from system?

Tags: macos

Some OS X apps register URL schemes and let users open the app directly through browser such as `macappstore://itunes.apple.com/us/app/unibox/id702816521?mt=12` to open the URL in Mac App Store.

Recently I downloaded [RCDefault](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) and discovered some of the URL schemes from apps I’ve removed — Steam for Mac and Monosnap — are still available.

Is there any way to remove those apps from the list? I’ve tried to use this command below to disassociate all the URL schemes relic, but the mentioned URL schemes are still visible.

`/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user`

Here’s the screenshot from RCDefault.

[image: OS X URL Schemes]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How long did you wait until checking the URL list?  Did you reboot?

After you reset the Launch Services database with that command, it will take a few minutes to rescan your system and rebuild the database.  During that time, the existing database will still be used.

I [wrote a blog post](http://www.insomniacsoftware.com/?p=61) about using this command to clean up the Open With contextual menu as it would often become corrupted and list applications multiple times.  When I would reset the database, I've seen it take over 30 minutes until the menu is correct again.

If you still have the app installed, or you can reinstall it, you can use the `lsregister -u PATH` command to unregister an application, which removes the associated URL Schemes.  For example, I still have TurboTax from 2011 installed and in the URL Schemes list, it had a `com.intuit.turbotax.2011` scheme listed.  Using the `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -u /Applications/TurboTax\ Deluxe\ 2011.app` command, it removed ONLY that registered application from the Launch Services database so it didn't need to rebuild the entire database.  Upon launching the Defaults Apps preference pane, I don't see the `com.intuit.turbotax.2011` scheme listed anymore

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer you seek is over at the [superuser stack exchange](https://superuser.com/questions/548119/how-do-i-configure-custom-url-handlers-on-os-x).  The answer there shows the location of the file that registers the URL schemes, and even has a link to a free tool (actually, the same one you have screenshots of in the question) if you prefer not to edit by hand.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be in your /etc/hosts file, in which case you just open the file, and remove the line that refers to that address/url, then save the file ;)

Answer (score 0):

I thought it is very hard to wrote a long command, so I just remove the app from `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`, and it's okay.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this elsewhere, it's something utterly undocumented that I noticed just by playing around. It seems in Swift, LSSetDefaultHandlerForURLScheme() will take "None" as a valid option for the bundle ID of the handler.